# PyMC3 Normal with variance per column

Tags: python, pymc3, pymc

I am trying to define a pymc3.Normal variable with the following as mu:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

mx = np.array([[0.25 , 0.5  , 0.75 , 1.   ],    
               [0.25 , 0.333, 0.25 , 0.   ],
               [0.25 , 0.167, 0.   , 0.   ],
               [0.25 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]])
epsilon = pm.Gamma('epsilon', alpha=10, beta=10)
p_ = pm.Normal('p_', mu=mx, shape = mx.shape, sd = epsilon)
```

The problem is that all random variables in p_ get the same std (epsilon). I would like the first row to use epsilon1, the second row epsilon2 etc.

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can pass an argument for the `shape` parameter to achieve this.  To demonstrate this, let's make some fake data to pass as observed, where we use fixed values for epsilon that we can compare against the inferred ones.

## Example Model

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import arviz as az

# priors
mu = np.array([[0.25 , 0.5  , 0.75 , 1.   ],    
               [0.25 , 0.333, 0.25 , 0.   ],
               [0.25 , 0.167, 0.   , 0.   ],
               [0.25 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]])
alpha, beta = 10, 10

# fake data
np.random.seed(2019)

# row vector will use a different sd for each column
sd = np.random.gamma(alpha, 1.0/beta, size=(1,4))

# generate 100 fake observations of the (4,4) random variables
Y = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sd, size=(100,4,4))

# true column sd's
print(sd)
# [[0.90055471 1.24522079 0.85846659 1.19588367]]

# mean sd's per column
print(np.mean(np.std(Y, 0), 0))
# [0.92028042 1.24437592 0.83383181 1.22717313]

# model
with pm.Model() as model:
    # use a (1,4) matrix to pool variance by columns
    epsilon = pm.Gamma('epsilon', alpha=10, beta=10, shape=(1, mu.shape[1]))

    p_ = pm.Normal('p_', mu=mu, sd=epsilon, shape=mu.shape, observed=Y)

    trace = pm.sample(random_seed=2019)
```

This samples well, and gives the following summary

[image]

which clearly bound the true values of the standard deviations within the HPDs.

Comment: The sd is sd=epsilon which is of shape (1, mu.shape[1]). This does the trick?

Comment: @Eran yes, exactly